# Изменились требования к именам связующих таблиц после перехода с Hibernate на Spring Data? Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

После перехода со Spring  на Spring Boot возникла ошибка с именами связующих таблиц(в старой версии бд работала с таблицами вроде: user_quiz, quiz_question, а сейчас пытается найти: user_quizzes, quiz_questions), полученных в следствии связей @OneToMany и @ManyToOne.
Какие могут быть варианты решения данной проблемы?

Ошибка:

> сom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'quizzes.quiz_questions' doesn't exist

Структура БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Часть класса Quiz:

```
Entity
public class Quiz implements Comparable<Quiz>{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Question> questions =new TreeSet();
    @NotEmpty(message = "Заполните поле")
    @Size(min=5, max=90, message = "должно иметь 5-90 символов")
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Заполните поле")
    @Size(min=5, max=25, message = "должна иметь 5-25 символов")
    @Column(name="objective")
    private String objective;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private User creator;
```

Часть класса Question:

```
@Entity
public class Question implements Comparable<Question> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="multiple")
    private boolean multiple; //Multiple-choice question
    @Column(name="question")
    private String question;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Answer> answer;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_quiz")
    private Quiz quiz;

    public Question(){}
```

Comment: Это промежуточные таблицы, @ManyToMany?

Comment: А зачем вам промежуточная таблица в связях @OneToMany?

Comment: @RomanDanilov Да, эти таблицы сформировались автоматически после использования  hbm2ddl.auto.
И действительно- промежутойчной быть не должно. 
Где  и как я не правильно использовал связь один ко многим и многие к одному?

Comment: Связи написаны правильно, а вот промежуточных таблиц быть не должно

Comment: @RomanDanilov но почему тогда вылетает следующая ошибка?
Table 'quizzes.quiz_questions' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Удалил смежные таблицы из БД и изменил связи на:

```
   class Quiz{
       @OneToMany(mappedBy="quiz", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Question> questions =new TreeSet();
                      ...
    }
    class Question{
    @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_quiz")
        private Quiz quiz;
                      ...
    }
```